# Get a List of property name with Lambda

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression

I've this code:

```
    public string GetPropName<T1, T2>(Expression<Func<T1, T2>> expression)
    {
        var member = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (member != null) return member.Member.Name;
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
```

With it I can retrieve the name of a property with lamba:

```
string propName= GetPropName((MyObject o) => o.MyProperty);
// propName will be "MyProperty"
```

I want to achieve the same thing but the method should return a list of property name.
For example:

```
List<string> PropNames= GetPropName((MyObject o) => o.MyProp, o.MySecondProp, o.EtcProp);
//PropNames will contains "MyProp", "MySecondProp", "EtcProp"
```

Do you think it's possible?

Thanks in advance

Edit:

p.s.w.g answer works well!

I've found another alternative:

```
public List<String> GetPropNames<T>(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
{
    var result = new List<String>();
    foreach (var navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
    {
        var member = navigationProperty.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (member == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        result.Add(member.Member.Name);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then I can call it this way:

```
List<String> MyProps= GetPropNames<MyObject>(e => e.MyFirstProp, e => e.MySecondProp,e=> MyEtcProp);
```

It works too. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use `nameof` instead? This sort of thing was useful before `nameof`, but doesn't serve much purpose now, IMO.

Comment: Visual studio 2013. I don't think I can use it... :(

Comment: Hmm. I'd personally try to upgrade to a newer version of Visual Studio rather than have to mess with expression trees...

Comment: I don't think I'll be able to convince my boss, I've to deal with this version of C# and Vs unfortunately.

Comment: Is it that complicated to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Jon Skeet's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41447299/get-a-list-of-property-name-with-lambda#comment70100866_41447299): `nameof` is a better way to get arbitrary property names. But assuming that's absolutely not an option, here's one way to do it using expression trees:

```
public string[] GetPropNames<T1, T2>(Expression<Func<T1, T2>> expression)
{
    var newExp = expression.Body as NewExpression;
    if (newExp == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    var props = new List<string>(newExp.Arguments.Count);
    foreach (var argExp in newExp.Arguments)
    {
        var memberExp = argExp as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExp == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        props.Add(memberExp.Member.Name);
    }
    return props.ToArray();
}
```

Usage:

```
GetPropNames((MyObject o) => new { o.MyProp, o.MySecondProp, o.EtcProp })
```

This is pretty brittle, but it should demonstrate the general principle.

Comment: Thank a lots! I've added an alternative solution in the main post. Don't hesitate to tell me what you think about it!

Comment: @Speuline Your solution works, too. I prefer the syntax of only having one expression with `new { … }`, but it's really just a matter of taste.

Comment: Yeah that is what I thought! Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I just want to answer this **** question because I google it to find the syntax and this thread is always in top so I'm writing it basically for future me:

This is query way:

```
var listOfThePropertyUNeed = (from e in TheParentListUWantItFrom select e.thePropertyUWantToReturn).toArray();
```

This is lamda way:

```
var listOfThePropertyUNeed = employees.Select(e => e.thePropertyUWantToReturn).ToArray();
```

You can do whatever with those lists